# ¿Como hacer un Foreach en un SQLite DataReader?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, sqlite, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy intentando obtener los datos de una consulta SQLite para luego guardar los campos en una lista y mostrárselos al usuario mediante un MessageBox.
Tengo dos problemas:
1) No sé si lo que estoy haciendo está bien.
2) No me compila el código, y no sé porque!

Acá les dejo lo que tengo:

```
        var lista= new List<string>();

        string nombre = "";
        string mesa = this.numMesa.Trim();
        String consulta_productos = "Select nombre from Productos where mesa = @mesa";
        SQLiteCommand comd = new SQLiteCommand(consulta_productos, conexion);
        comd.Parameters.Clear();
        comd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@mesa", mesa));
        comd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        using (SQLiteDataReader read = comd.ExecuteReader())
        {
                foreach (string i in read)
                {
                    // acá me tira error
                    lista.Add(read.GetString(i));
                }
        }
```

El compilador me tira un error que dice "cannot convert string to int" en la línea que les marco más arriba. No entiendo porque. Intente de poner i.toString() y tampoco compila.

Está bien hecho el foreach ?? Y a que se refiere con que no puede convertir string a int si no tengo ningún int ?? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El parámetro de `.GetString()` es un entero que corresponde al número de columna (que comienza en 0) del resultado. Este número de columna puede ser calculado en base al nombre de la columna mediante `.GetOrdinal("nombreDeColumna")`

En tu caso, reemplaza el `foreach` por lo siguiente:

```
while (read.Read())
{
    lista.Add(read.GetString(read.GetOrdinal("nombre")));
}
```

Además el `comd.ExecuteNonQuery();` no tiene sentido ya que lo que estás ejecutando es precisamente un query. Simplemente bórralo.

`comd.Parameters.Clear();` es otra línea que está de más, si acabas de instanciar el `SQLiteCommand` no tiene ningún parámetro por lo que no tiene sentido limpiarlo.

Además puedes aprovechar de usar `var` en lugar de repetir el tipo de dato en algunos lados.

También puedes aprovechar los inicializadores de objetos para escirbir el códidgo de forma más compacta.

Todo puede quedar de la sgte manera:

```
var consultaProductos = "Select nombre from Productos where mesa = @mesa";
using (var comd = new SQLiteCommand(consultaProductos, conexion)
{
    Parameters =
    {
        new SQLiteParameter("@mesa", mesa)
    }
})
{
    using (var read = comd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (read.Read())
        {
            lista.Add(read.GetString(read.GetOrdinal("nombre")));
        }
    }
}
```